# WPF Binding in Custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to create custom control and have some problem with binding.

This is my property:

```
public DateTime? SelectedDate
{
    get
    {
        return (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); ;
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
    }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedDate",
    typeof(DateTime?),
    typeof(ValidationDateSelector),
    new PropertyMetadata(null));

...

private void ChengeSelectedDate()
{
    if (_day != 0 && _month != 0 && _year != 0)
    {
        SelectedDate = new DateTime(_year, _month, _day);
        OnSelectedDateChenged();
    }
}

...

public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SelectedDateChanged;
private void OnSelectedDateChenged()
{
    if (SelectedDateChanged != null)
        SelectedDateChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

And binding in XAML:

```
    <Ctrl:DateSelector x:Name="ValidationDateSelector"
SelectedDate="{Binding DateOfBirth, Mode=TwoWay}"
SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged"/>
```

So Binding doesn't work but DateSelector.SelectedDate is prathent and I can assign value in code to DateOfBirth. Why? What wrong in my logic?

Comment: how does DateOfBirth in the ViewModel look like ?

Comment: The event handler is named differently in the xaml and also you are not handling the property change when you register the dependency property. What calls ChengeSelectedDate?